# While and past simple

Tags: past-tense, tense-agreement

Could you explain me why in this sentence "drop" or "dance" are past simple?

Here is the sentence:

> "If Satan had a pool party, the F.P would have be playing loudly in the background while everyone **dropped** acid and **danced** like it was 1969."

I would write "Would be dropping and would be dancing" or "would drop and would dance" as it is not a real situation I would use "would".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The past tense is established in the first part of the sentence:

> If Satan **had** a ...

So it would be inappropriate to use present tense for the other verbs.

The hypothetical is established at the beginning of the second clause:

> the F.P **would have *been*** playing...   *(corrected to past tense)*

So it is unnecessary to use "would" with the other verbs, as it is implied and would sound repetitive.

It would probably be a good idea to correct the sentence to have all verbs in the same tense, though. I would do this by changing "would have been playing" to "would have played", though this is not strictly necessary.